# Azure Blob Shared Access Signature without the api

Tags: silverlight, rest, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to create a REST call to Azure to List Blobs within a container.  The container is private so I need to access it through a Shared Access Signature (SAS).

I make that call in a Silverlight application so I cannot use the Client API.

I find a lot of examples with ClientAPI but nothing really clear and obvious for REST.

Anyone has a nice... clean and simple example on how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a blog post a few days ago about exactly the same: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/13/revisiting-windows-azure-shared-access-signature/. I've included samples for various common functions both using REST API and Client library. As far as listing blobs is concerned, if you use REST API you get raw XML back which you would need to parse in your SL app.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I have found your blog before entry asking here! I'm the one who posted a comment yesterday on it.  Many thanks!!! Daniel